# How to combine monthly results into a single row?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

If have a sales table with data like:

```
SALES
-----
seller_id month amount
1         1     10
1         2     15
```

I would like to retrieve all seller's sales in a single row. How can I combine the results from the table into a result like this?

```
seller_id    jan_amount    feb_amount  
    1            10            15
```

EDIT:

I can retrieve the monthly sales with this query:

```
select    seller_id, month, sum(amount)
from      sales
group by  sellerd_id, month
```

But it gives me results like:

```
1,1,10
1,2,15
```

I'm hoping to transform this into:

```
1, 10 as JAN_AMOUNT, 15 as FEB_AMONT
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you try to get the sum by seller and month first?  Thats a two step process what do you have?  What SQL are you using?

Comment: Do you try something like this "SELECT  SUM(amount) AS total_amount FROM SALES WHERE seller_id = 1"

Comment: @Brad I added the sql I've tried, I hadn't included it initially because it doesn't produce the result I'm looking for

Comment: @Bast yes, I edited my question to reflect this

Comment: You need to look into PIVOT

Comment: Have you ever heard of `PIVOT`?

Comment: by the what's your DBMS? Since you can use `pivot` keyword depending on your DBMS. Some of them supports that.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use *conditional aggregation* to *pivot* your data with the following SQL statement as :

```
select seller_id,
       max(case when month = 1 then amount end  ) as jan_amount,
       max(case when month = 2 then amount end  ) as feb_amount
  from sales
 where seller_id = 1
 group by seller_id;

 SELLER_ID  JAN_AMOUNT  FEB_AMOUNT
 ---------  ----------  ----------
    1           10          15
```

As an Oracle user, you may use the following SQL statement with `pivot` keyword as :

```
select *
  from sales
 pivot(
       sum(amount)
       for(month)
        in (1 as jan_amount ,2 as feb_amount )
   );

 SELLER_ID  JAN_AMOUNT  FEB_AMOUNT
 ---------  ----------  ----------
    1           10          15
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/BLCX40690)